# Initialise a structure containing a union

Tags: c, struct, unions

I have some code as follows

```
typedef struct _DisplayString
{
    char* string;
}DisplayString;

typedef struct _DisplayGroup
{
    char groupName[10];
    int groupType;
}DisplayGroup;

typedef struct _Info {
    int x;
    union display
    {
        DisplayString displayString;
        DisplayGroup  displayGroup;
    }Display;
}Info;


int main(void) {

    DisplayString stringType;
    DisplayGroup groupType;
    Info infoField = { 0, {stringType}};
    Info groupFields = { 0, {groupType}};
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to initialise the structure fields. 
I am getting a compiler error on the line initialising the groupFields data variable

```
gcc -Wall -g settings.c 
settings.c: In function ‘main’:
settings.c:29:5: warning: missing braces around initializer [-Wmissing-braces]
settings.c:29:5: warning: (near initialization for ‘groupFields.Display.displayString’) [-Wmissing-braces]
settings.c:29:5: error: incompatible types when initializing type ‘char *’ using type ‘DisplayGroup’
settings.c:29:10: warning: unused variable ‘groupFields’ [-Wunused-variable]
settings.c:28:10: warning: unused variable ‘infoField’ [-Wunused-variable]
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Don't use leading underscore followed by a capital letter, such names are reserved by the specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this explicit definition helps you see what is going on:

```
Info infoField = { .x = 0, .Display = {.displayString = stringType}};
Info groupFields = { .x = 0, .Display = {.displayGroup = groupType}};
```

You have to at least define which union variant you choose:

```
Info infoField = { 0, {.displayString = stringType}};
Info groupFields = { 0, {.displayGroup = groupType}};
```

Answer (score 2):

In your declaration:

```
Info groupFields = { 0, {groupType}};
```

`groupType` value is of type `DisplayGroup` which is not the type of the first `union display` member. A union may only be initialized with a value of the type of its first member, i.e, an initializer of type `DisplayString` here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should declare the **display** union as:

```
union display
{
    DisplayString displayString;
    DisplayGroup  displayGroup;
};
```

Or:

```
typedef union display
{
    DisplayString displayString;
    DisplayGroup  displayGroup;
}Display;
```

I just tried to compile with gcc. The original code has a compiling error: "incompatible types when initializing type ‘char *’ using type ‘DisplayGroup’" .Now, there is no more one.

Comment: The first one make the union unnamed, so it can't be referenced by name anymore, which might need refactoring of the OPs code (maybe a lot of work). The second example doesn't create a member `Display`, but a type alias `Display`.